# Conditions on matrix entries for the matrix to be diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-rank

I am seeking verification of my solution to the below problem, or tips on how my solution can be improved. Here is the problem:

For which complex numbers $a,b,c,d$ is the matrix \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c & d \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Here is my approach to the problem:

Denote the above matrix by $A$. Then $A$  is diagonalizable if and only if for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is equal to the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$.

One can quickly calculate the characteristic polynomial of $A$, and find that it is given by $p_A(x) = (1-x)^2(2-x)^2$. Thus, we have two eigenvalues $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = 2$, both with algebraic multiplicity $2$. Thus, $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda = 1$ is $2$ and the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda = 2$ is $2$.

$A-1I = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & a & b \\
0 & 0 & c & d \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$. We need the dimension of the null space of $A - 1I$ to be equal to $2$ in order for $A$ to be diagonalizable. Using the rank-nullity theorem, this is equivalent to asking that the rank of $A - 1I$ is equal to $2$, i.e., that there are two nonzero rows in the row echelon form of $A-1I$. I claim this occurs if:

$1)$ $a,b,c,d$ are all equal to $0$,

$2)$ $a,d \neq 0$ and $b,c = 0$

$3$ $a,d = 0$ and $b,c \neq 0$

$A-2I = \begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & a & b \\
0 & -1 & c & d \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$. Similar to the above, we need two nonzero rows in the row echelon form of $A-2I$ in order for $A$ to be diagonalizable. But I claim this happens for any $a,b,c,d$ here, so we don't gain any new conditions on $a,b,c,d$ here.

Thus, my final answer is that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ only if one of the following occurs:

$1)$ $a,b,c,d$ are all equal to $0$,

$2)$ $a,d \neq 0$ and $b,c = 0$

$3$ $a,d = 0$ and $b,c \neq 0$

Is my solution correct? If not, where did I make an error in my logic? Is there any ways my solution can be improved?

Thanks!

Comment: You got the answer, when you get the null space $A-I$, put this directly, compute the dimension in terms of $a,b,c,d$. In fact $A-I$ is rank $2$ as $A-2I$ for any $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your conditions for $\lambda=1$ should be the same as for $\lambda=2$.  Because no matter what $a,b,c,d$ are, you can do row operations to remove them.  Does that make sense?

Try it in [this Sage cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzyMwrSS1KTC7h5UpJTVOI10i0NdVJsjXTSba10EmxNTLWtOLlUgACXwVbhdzEkqLMCo3AwOjMWB0TnWhDHQOdRJ0kIGmok6yTAqQNdIzAJJgVqwnRWlAEtETDVy-zOD4lMzE9Py8xJ7MqMSknVUNTEwCJ6yJ5&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), which also shows the [Jordan canonical form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordanCanonicalForm.html) over a certain subfield of the complex numbers.  (And compare to [this one](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtTcsKgzAQvAv-Q44JLEXtg1II9Ac8eBYJm0TbLZqUGGjp13exncPMwMwwVwp5TOhyWfhxEkaiPoLVJ3D6DF43e3UpC8FohRYL5kRv2XU9DXCAvoYaECxUrA48awXNxpsb1G_6THwi2x2txhPeYsCZPmjnUap_Y73HFxceMXkMZopp4egLkbUqgA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), which now is not diagonalizable at all, with just one entry different, $a_{12}=1$.)

Answer (score 1):

As,eigenvalue of this matrix are 1 and 2.if matrix A is diagonalizable then minimial polynomial of A is (A-I)(A-2I) so we put A in this equation then I found that a,b,c,d be any number